# Беспрерывная работа аудио плеера на всех страницах

Tags: jquery, html, html5, javascript

Добрый день, помогите советом. На сайте есть плеер, хочу реализовать беспрерывную работу на всех страница, чтобы человек мог нормально послушать понравившуюся песню и мог продолжить нормально перемещаться по сайту. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Открывай плеер отдельной вкладкой.
Вариант 2. Используй фреймы
Вариант 3. Используй AJAX

Comment: ну на сколько я понимаю AJAX вообще не вариант так как не будет индексироватся из-за отсутствия ссылок. Вкладка тоже не вариант (по крайней мере для меня). Подробнее о фреймах можно? Спасибо.

Comment: Ajax не вариант? Что-то новенькое. И при чем тут "отсутствие ссылок"? Вам кто-то запрещает их использовать?

Comment: Подскажите тогда каким образом будет происходить переходы по сайту без полной перезагрузки страницы и при этом с навигацией по линкам. Спасибо.

Comment: Про *HTML5 History API* что-нибудь слышали? Даже под jQuery уже есть [готовое решение][1].

   [1]:https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

Comment: Конечно не слышали, потому и спрашиваем. Спасибо, буду изучать материал.